# Average from arguments

Tags: java, average, args

I have this code to get the average from args:

```
public class Mariamne
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("\n");
        try
        {
            int sum = 0;
            float prom = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<=args.length; i++)
            {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                sum = a + sum;
                prom = prom + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(sum/prom);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I can't get it to work (without the exception it says "array out of bounds"), is there a way to define the size of the args? please help!

Comment: You should debug before posting :p You would have noticed that you can only go out of bounds at one point, and it does in fact overloop. I'm saying this since you seem to be aware of 0-indexing. See below. Stuff to print: index currently used, length of array. #Indexes = length + 1

Comment: It should be `i < args.length` as the first is `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access the index `args.length`. Change your `for` to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) // Without the = in the condition
```

In any array, the maximum accessible index is always `array.length - 1`. And that is why when you try to access the `args.length` index in `args` array, it throws the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks!! that worked just fine. So what you're saying is that if an array has 2 elements it's length is actually 1?

Comment: No, its length is 2, but the highest index is 1.

Comment: Nope, if the array has 2 elements, its length is 2, but arrays have 0-based index. The 2 values are stored at the index `array[0]` and `array[1]`. If you try to do `array[2]`, it'd technically mean the third element, but hey, your array has only 2 elements. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the index limit of args for int variable i.
Index can be between 0 to len-1.
Simply replace `i<=args.length` with `i<args.length`  or `i<=args.length-1`.